# how can I make my alert box according to message in android

Tags: android

How can I make alert box background color,button size message will be center align,alertbox size.can it is Possible to do.

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: ur question is not clear my friend. plz elaborate

Comment: Actually what i want that My alert box will come according to the message means.like "Do you want to logout?"so Need backgound color.Title center align.like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. here is the deal. I have used few drawable for my below custom Dialog layout. So you have to create your own Drawables according to the size.

my **custom_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/custom_alert_bg">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main_layout" android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <ImageView android:background="@drawable/alert_dialog_icon" android:id="@+id/alert_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/alert_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/alert_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Alert Title"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/seperator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/line">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/alert_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seperator">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/alert_content_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Alert Content"></TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/alert_ok_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/alert_description"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/alert_ok_button"
    android:gravity="center">
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java method to use this layout as your custom dialog,

```
    public static void warningDialog(final Context context,String title,String message){
         dialog=new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    Button ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_ok_button);
    TextView alert_title=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_title);
    TextView alert_content=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_content_text);

    alert_title.setText(title);
    alert_title.setTextSize(22);
    alert_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    alert_content.setText(message);
    alert_content.setTextSize(18);
    alert_content.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    ok.setText("ok");
ok.setTextSize(20);
ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog.cancel();


    }
});
        dialog.show();
    }
```

That's it. Your custom dialog is ready..,

Now call this method in your activity,

```
warningDialog(this,"Alert",msg);
```

Comment: Hii Andro!! I am getting stuck with this code that is..one time it is done but for the next time..it is not working.same..when I click the button  I am not getting custom dialog.is anything wrong

Comment: I didn't come across this kind of incident. It works fine for me. Please check it once again. Bcoz there is nothing it has to do with click events. :)